# Attributes that implement other attributes

Tags: c#, oop, attributes

I want to facade or proxy a library's implemented attribute.
for example the property mapping attributes.

I want to control which of the libraries attributes to be used in project.
some kind of a DI or Module control.
Is there an easy way to achieve it without using reflection?

something to transfer these two types of attributes into one:

```
[MapsFromAndToProperty(typeof(fooClass), nameof(fooClass.PropertyName))]
```

and

```
[AdaptMember(name)]
```

into

```
[MyAttributeToControlWhichOneToUse(typeof(fooClass), nameof(fooClass.PropertyName))]
```

And Thank you for your attention.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do will work. The problem is that the library is going to look for its attribute and interpret it according to its own logic. If you define another attribute, the library doesn't know to look for it or what it means. If it's your library then you can modify it to look for the new attribute. But if it's a 3rd-party library then unless you do some really, really complicated stuff I don't even want to imagine, I don't think you can accomplish what you're describing.

Comment: Perhaps you could just create a new class that holds an instance of the "fooClass". You would be completely free in how you would want to allow/deny access to the "fooClass". Followed by doing that, you could just use that new class from then on.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, it is not possible to alter attributes in the general case. This is simply because attributes are effectively part of the assembly metadata and doing what you want means to change that assembly metadata.

There are two ways how this could potentially work, though:

1. You do change the assembly metadata. Here, you are in the realm of aspect-oriented programming. You could try to create an aspect e.g. based on PostSharp that unrolls your `MyAttributeToControlWhichOneToUse` attribute into the required attributes at compile-time. This solution is independent of the way how the attributs are read, but requires changes to the build infrastructure.
2. You alter the way how the attributes are loaded. MEF is an example that does that for its convention-based programming model that effectively emulates attributes on the conventional classes by altering the way how attributes are retrieved. This only works, if foreseen in the lib that reads the properties (and honestly, I have never seen anybody else than MEF to do that).